# Drawing a rotated rectangle in python 3, pygame

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a simple game in Python 3 and I need to draw a rectangle rotated by a given angle and around a specific centre of rotation.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The values don't really matter I would just like to know how the functions to rotate a rectangle work. For example how would I draw a rectangle rotated 30 degrees from the x axis?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using the pygame library, the `pygame.transform.rotate(*Surface*,*angle*)` function may be worth a try.

Without a code sample it is hard to understand the context you are trying to apply this in.